# Android Wear Notification Dismissed Listener

Tags: android, wear-os

Has anybody found a way to trigger a callback/listener when a notification has been dismissed?  Or any way to send a message or alter a data item on dismiss?
It seems to me this would be helpful for collecting analytics, but I haven't found a mechanism that allows for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NotificationCompat.Builder.setDeleteIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) (or the equivalent in Notification.Builder if you are doing local notifications on the Android Wear device) allows you to set a `PendingIntent` that will be called when your notification is dismissed.